# Repeat CSS keyframing animation

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

I'm making an effect on an SVG vector and would like to repeat the animations

the idea is

`layer_1` appears and disappears

`layer_2` appears and disappears

`layer_3` appears and disappears

`layer_4` appears and disappears

`layer_5` appears, waits 3 seconds and disappears and repeats everything again

what i have so far

```css
.wrapper {
  background: #364254;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#layer_1,
#layer_2,
#layer_3,
#layer_4,
#layer_5 {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#layer_1 {
  animation: toggle 0.1s;
}

#layer_2 {
  animation: toggle 0.1s;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

#layer_3 {
  animation: toggle 0.1s;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

#layer_4 {
  animation: toggle 0.1s;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

#layer_5 {
  animation: last 3s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes toggle {
  0% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  50% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@keyframes last {
  0% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  1% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 592.4733 217.3301">
      <defs>
        <radialGradient
          id="radial-gradient"
          cx="364.6661"
          cy="36.8007"
          r="169.8647"
          gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
          <stop
            offset="0"
            stop-color="#f27075"
          />
          <stop
            offset="1"
            stop-color="#364254"
            stop-opacity="0"
          />
        </radialGradient>
      </defs>
      <g style="isolation: isolate">
        <g id="zero">
          <g>
            <circle
              cx="283.1367"
              cy="118.3301"
              r="99"
              fill="url(#radial-gradient)"
            />
            <g
              opacity="0.3"
              style="mix-blend-mode: multiply"
            >
              <path
                d="M344.1367,49.33c-22.4594-27.3419-42-2-23,23S367.1367,77.33,344.1367,49.33Z"
                fill="none"
                stroke="#f27075"
                stroke-miterlimit="10"
              />
              <path
                d="M306.1367,83.33c-14.8913-10.7356-40,18-20,40S349.1367,114.33,306.1367,83.33Z"
                fill="none"
                stroke="#f27075"
                stroke-miterlimit="10"
              />
              <path
                d="M366.1367,111.33c-6.23-6.7962-13,10-7,18S377.1367,123.33,366.1367,111.33Z"
                fill="none"
                stroke="#f27075"
                stroke-miterlimit="10"
              />
              <path
                d="M291.1367,28.33c-7.25-.6591-10,8-3,11S302.1367,29.33,291.1367,28.33Z"
                fill="none"
                stroke="#f27075"
                stroke-miterlimit="10"
              />
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g id="layer_5">
          <path
            d="M571.4733,120.6513,561.306,147.0922a2.2762,2.2762,0,0,1-2.2841,1.5766H542.9943c-1.2305,0-1.93-.8767-1.4074-2.2842l9.9058-25.7333Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M571.235,109.2843l-4.3761,11.367H546.8782l4.33-11.2517L536.9647,72.553c-.5306-1.4074.1769-2.2764,1.4075-2.2764h16.02a2.2613,2.2613,0,0,1,2.2843,1.5766Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M37.8628,148.6688H21.8352a2.2764,2.2764,0,0,1-2.2842-1.5766L5,109.6534,9.353,98.348H29.3337l-4.3069,11.1978L39.27,146.3846C39.7932,147.7921,39.0933,148.6688,37.8628,148.6688Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M163.2612,120.69V33.0454H109.7256L56.19,124.72v10.5441h124.13V120.69Zm-40.269-26.2948V120.69H95.0362l.2384-.4691,13.0282-25.5873c5.6912-10.6594,9.9519-20.6113,14.9278-31.0324h.946C123.7074,74.4988,122.9922,84.4507,122.9922,94.3949Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <g>
            <path
              d="M500.1028,120.69V33.0454H459.6645V64.4623c.1307-.2845.2692-.5768.4077-.8614h.9459c-.4768,10.8979-1.1844,20.85-1.1844,30.794V120.69h-27.956l.2383-.4691,8.7907-17.2582h-35.17L393.0315,124.72v27.7176h66.8022v34.5855h40.2691V152.4373h17.0581V120.69Z"
              fill="#fff"
            />
            <path
              d="M455.05,33.0454V64.4623c-4.8067,10.1057-8.99,19.8038-14.52,30.171l-4.2376,8.3291h-35.17l40.83-69.917Z"
              fill="#fff"
            />
          </g>
          <text
            transform="translate(112.0068 17)"
            font-size="20"
            fill="#fff"
            font-family="Montserrat-Black, Montserrat"
            font-weight="800"
          >Er<tspan
              x="22.5796"
              y="0"
              letter-spacing="-0.005em"
            >r</tspan>
            <tspan
              x="31.5996"
              y="0"
            >or</tspan>
          </text>
          <polygon
            points="191.087 137.571 191.087 154.745 174.028 154.745 174.028 172.18 133.759 172.18 133.759 154.745 66.957 154.745 66.957 137.571 191.087 137.571"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <rect
            x="129.1448"
            y="172.1796"
            width="40.269"
            height="17.1505"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M43.8693,72.553,33.9482,98.348H13.9674l10.19-26.4948a2.2672,2.2672,0,0,1,2.2841-1.5766H42.47C43.7,70.2766,44.4,71.1456,43.8693,72.553Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
        </g>
        <g id="layer_1">
          <path
            d="M562.4733,120.6513,552.306,147.0922a2.2762,2.2762,0,0,1-2.2841,1.5766H533.9943c-1.2305,0-1.93-.8767-1.4074-2.2842l9.9058-25.7333Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M571.235,120.2843l-4.3761,11.367H546.8782l4.33-11.2517L536.9647,83.553c-.5306-1.4074.1769-2.2764,1.4075-2.2764h16.02a2.2613,2.2613,0,0,1,2.2843,1.5766Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M32.8628,148.6688H16.8352a2.2764,2.2764,0,0,1-2.2842-1.5766L0,109.6534,4.353,98.348H24.3337l-4.3069,11.1978L34.27,146.3846C34.7932,147.7921,34.0933,148.6688,32.8628,148.6688Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M193.2612,120.69V33.0454H139.7256L86.19,124.72v10.5441h124.13V120.69Zm-40.269-26.2948V120.69h-27.956l.2384-.4691,13.0282-25.5873c5.6912-10.6594,9.9519-20.6113,14.9278-31.0324h.946C153.7074,74.4988,152.9922,84.4507,152.9922,94.3949Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M506.1028,113.69V26.0454H465.6645V57.4623c.1307-.2845.2692-.5768.4077-.8614h.9459c-.4768,10.8979-1.1844,20.85-1.1844,30.794V113.69h-27.956l.2383-.4691,8.7907-17.2582h-35.17L399.0315,117.72v27.7176h66.8022v34.5855h40.2691V145.4373h17.0581V113.69Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M442.05,33.0454V64.4623c-4.8067,10.1057-8.99,19.8038-14.52,30.171l-4.2376,8.3291h-35.17l40.83-69.917Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <text
            transform="translate(112.0068 17)"
            font-size="20"
            fill="#fff"
            font-family="Montserrat-Black, Montserrat"
            font-weight="800"
          >Er<tspan
              x="22.5796"
              y="0"
              letter-spacing="-0.005em"
            >r</tspan>
            <tspan
              x="31.5996"
              y="0"
            >or</tspan>
          </text>
          <polygon
            points="165.087 137.571 165.087 154.745 148.028 154.745 148.028 172.18 107.759 172.18 107.759 154.745 40.957 154.745 40.957 137.571 165.087 137.571"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <rect
            x="129.1448"
            y="172.1796"
            width="40.269"
            height="17.1505"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M47.8693,91.553l-9.9211,25.795H17.9674l10.19-26.4948a2.2672,2.2672,0,0,1,2.2841-1.5766H46.47C47.7,89.2766,48.4,90.1456,47.8693,91.553Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
        </g>
        <g id="layer_2">
          <path
            d="M567.4733,123.6513,557.306,150.0922a2.2762,2.2762,0,0,1-2.2841,1.5766H538.9943c-1.2305,0-1.93-.8767-1.4074-2.2842l9.9058-25.7333Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M562.235,120.2843l-4.3761,11.367H537.8782l4.33-11.2517L527.9647,83.553c-.5306-1.4074.1769-2.2764,1.4075-2.2764h16.02a2.2613,2.2613,0,0,1,2.2843,1.5766Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M37.8628,148.6688H21.8352a2.2764,2.2764,0,0,1-2.2842-1.5766L5,109.6534,9.353,98.348H29.3337l-4.3069,11.1978L39.27,146.3846C39.7932,147.7921,39.0933,148.6688,37.8628,148.6688Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M193.2612,120.69V33.0454H139.7256L86.19,124.72v10.5441h124.13V120.69Zm-40.269-26.2948V120.69h-27.956l.2384-.4691,13.0282-25.5873c5.6912-10.6594,9.9519-20.6113,14.9278-31.0324h.946C153.7074,74.4988,152.9922,84.4507,152.9922,94.3949Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M506.1028,119.69V32.0454H465.6645V63.4623c.1307-.2845.2692-.5768.4077-.8614h.9459c-.4768,10.8979-1.1844,20.85-1.1844,30.794V119.69h-27.956l.2383-.4691,8.7907-17.2582h-35.17L399.0315,123.72v27.7176h66.8022v34.5855h40.2691V151.4373h17.0581V119.69Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M445.05,42.0454V73.4623c-4.8067,10.1057-8.99,19.8038-14.52,30.171l-4.2376,8.3291h-35.17l40.83-69.917Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <text
            transform="translate(112.0068 17)"
            font-size="20"
            fill="#fff"
            font-family="Montserrat-Black, Montserrat"
            font-weight="800"
          >Er<tspan
              x="22.5796"
              y="0"
              letter-spacing="-0.005em"
            >r</tspan>
            <tspan
              x="31.5996"
              y="0"
            >or</tspan>
          </text>
          <polygon
            points="220.087 137.571 220.087 154.745 203.028 154.745 203.028 172.18 162.759 172.18 162.759 154.745 95.957 154.745 95.957 137.571 220.087 137.571"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <rect
            x="177.7041"
            y="160.6203"
            width="17.1505"
            height="40.269"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M52.8693,87.553l-9.9211,25.795H22.9674l10.19-26.4948a2.2672,2.2672,0,0,1,2.2841-1.5766H51.47C52.7,85.2766,53.4,86.1456,52.8693,87.553Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
        </g>
        <g id="layer_3">
          <path
            d="M592.4733,114.6513,582.306,141.0922a2.2762,2.2762,0,0,1-2.2841,1.5766H563.9943c-1.2305,0-1.93-.8767-1.4074-2.2842l9.9058-25.7333Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M590.235,163.2843l-4.3761,11.367H565.8782l4.33-11.2517L555.9647,126.553c-.5306-1.4074.1769-2.2764,1.4075-2.2764h16.02a2.2613,2.2613,0,0,1,2.2843,1.5766Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M48.8628,167.6688H32.8352a2.2764,2.2764,0,0,1-2.2842-1.5766L16,128.6534l4.353-11.3054H40.3337l-4.3069,11.1978L50.27,165.3846C50.7932,166.7921,50.0933,167.6688,48.8628,167.6688Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M169.2612,131.69V44.0454H115.7256L62.19,135.72v10.5441h124.13V131.69Zm-40.269-26.2948V131.69h-27.956l.2384-.4691,13.0282-25.5873c5.6912-10.6594,9.9519-20.6113,14.9278-31.0324h.946C129.7074,85.4988,128.9922,95.4507,128.9922,105.3949Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M506.1067,119.69V32.05h-40.44V63.46c.13-.28.27-.57.41-.86h.94c-.48,10.9-1.18,20.85-1.18,30.79v26.3h-27.96l.24-.47,8.79-17.26h-35.17l-12.71,21.76v27.72h66.81v6.89h40.27v-6.89h17.05V119.69Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M477.05,12.0454V43.4623c-4.8067,10.1057-8.99,19.8038-14.52,30.171l-4.2376,8.3291h-35.17l40.83-69.917Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <text
            transform="translate(112.0068 17)"
            font-size="20"
            fill="#fff"
            font-family="Montserrat-Black, Montserrat"
            font-weight="800"
          >Er<tspan
              x="22.5796"
              y="0"
              letter-spacing="-0.005em"
            >r</tspan>
            <tspan
              x="31.5996"
              y="0"
            >or</tspan>
          </text>
          <polygon
            points="204.087 124.571 204.087 141.745 187.028 141.745 187.028 159.18 146.759 159.18 146.759 141.745 79.957 141.745 79.957 124.571 204.087 124.571"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <rect
            x="209.7041"
            y="112.6203"
            width="17.1505"
            height="40.269"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M52.8693,87.553l-9.9211,25.795H22.9674l10.19-26.4948a2.2672,2.2672,0,0,1,2.2841-1.5766H51.47C52.7,85.2766,53.4,86.1456,52.8693,87.553Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <rect
            x="447.8366"
            y="158.3301"
            width="40.27"
            height="27.69"
            fill="#fff"
          />
        </g>
        <g id="layer_4">
          <path
            d="M578.4733,140.6513,568.306,167.0922a2.2762,2.2762,0,0,1-2.2841,1.5766H549.9943c-1.2305,0-1.93-.8767-1.4074-2.2842l9.9058-25.7333Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M590.235,163.2843l-4.3761,11.367H565.8782l4.33-11.2517L555.9647,126.553c-.5306-1.4074.1769-2.2764,1.4075-2.2764h16.02a2.2613,2.2613,0,0,1,2.2843,1.5766Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M48.8628,167.6688H32.8352a2.2764,2.2764,0,0,1-2.2842-1.5766L16,128.6534l4.353-11.3054H40.3337l-4.3069,11.1978L50.27,165.3846C50.7932,166.7921,50.0933,167.6688,48.8628,167.6688Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M169.2612,131.69V44.0454H115.7256L62.19,135.72v10.5441h124.13V131.69Zm-40.269-26.2948V131.69h-27.956l.2384-.4691,13.0282-25.5873c5.6912-10.6594,9.9519-20.6113,14.9278-31.0324h.946C129.7074,85.4988,128.9922,95.4507,128.9922,105.3949Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M506.1067,119.69V32.05h-40.44V63.46c.13-.28.27-.57.41-.86h.94c-.48,10.9-1.18,20.85-1.18,30.79v26.3h-27.96l.24-.47,8.79-17.26h-35.17l-12.71,21.76v27.72h66.81v6.89h40.27v-6.89h17.05V119.69Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M485.05,24.0454V55.4623c-4.8067,10.1057-8.99,19.8038-14.52,30.171l-4.2376,8.3291h-35.17l40.83-69.917Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <polygon
            points="186.087 162.571 186.087 179.745 169.028 179.745 169.028 197.18 128.759 197.18 128.759 179.745 61.957 179.745 61.957 162.571 186.087 162.571"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <rect
            x="71.7041"
            y="74.6203"
            width="17.1505"
            height="40.269"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <path
            d="M52.8693,87.553l-9.9211,25.795H22.9674l10.19-26.4948a2.2672,2.2672,0,0,1,2.2841-1.5766H51.47C52.7,85.2766,53.4,86.1456,52.8693,87.553Z"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <rect
            x="449.8366"
            y="176.3301"
            width="40.27"
            height="27.69"
            fill="#fff"
          />
          <text
            transform="translate(112.0068 17)"
            font-size="20"
            fill="#fff"
            font-family="Montserrat-Black, Montserrat"
            font-weight="800"
          >Er<tspan
              x="22.5796"
              y="0"
              letter-spacing="-0.005em"
            >r</tspan>
            <tspan
              x="31.5996"
              y="0"
            >or</tspan>
          </text>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it's what you're looking for:

```
.wrapper {
    background: #364254;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    from { opacity: 0 }
    15% { opacity: 0 }
    16% { opacity: 1 }
    18% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    to { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes blink {
    from { opacity: 0 }
    15% { opacity: 0 }
    16% { opacity: 1 }
    18% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    to { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes blink {
    from { opacity: 0 }
    15% { opacity: 0 }
    16% { opacity: 1 }
    18% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    to { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes blink {
    from { opacity: 0 }
    15% { opacity: 0 }
    16% { opacity: 1 }
    18% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    to { opacity: 0 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes last {
    from { opacity: 0 }
    1% { opacity: 1 }
    90% { opacity: 1 }
    to { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes last {
    from { opacity: 0 }
    1% { opacity: 1 }
    90% { opacity: 1 }
    to { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes last {
    from { opacity: 0 }
    1% { opacity: 1 }
    90% { opacity: 1 }
    to { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes last {
    from { opacity: 0 }
    1% { opacity: 1 }
    90% { opacity: 1 }
    to { opacity: 0 }
}
#layer_1,
#layer_2,
#layer_3,
#layer_4 {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-name: blink;
    animation-duration: 3.8s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
#layer_2 {
    animation-delay: .2s;
}
#layer_3 {
    animation-delay: .4s;
}
#layer_4 {
    animation-delay: .6s;
}
#layer_5 {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-name: last;
    animation-duration: 3.8s;
    animation-delay: .8s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Comment: the animation happens, but not from the 3 second pause at last and doesn't repeat :(

Comment: You want it to start after 3 sec and loop forever? Is that what you want or I'm mistaken?

Comment: as i said in my question `layer_5 appears, waits 3 seconds and disappears and repeats everything again`

Comment: when layer_5 appears, you need to keep it visible for 3 seconds, then repeat it again

Comment: You mentioned it. I forgot. I'm modifying codes to approach that. Wait...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197896/discussion-between-amin-shahrokhi-and-yung-silva).

Comment: This is working on JSFiddle. Unless what it's doing is not what you need:

https://jsfiddle.net/aminshahrokhi/gt6mLqdx/

Comment: This is not the behavior I want.

In my question I detail well ... layer_1 appears and disappears, only then appears layer_2 and so on ...

Comment: I want the same behavior as your previous answer, but it only keeps the layer_5 visible for 3 seconds, disappears and repeated all over again.

Comment: I know Yung. Edited again. Try it now. Though, duration can be moderated again. But it's what you wanted anyway.

Comment: still wrong, not the behavior I want, I have no other way to explain ... I think I explained as clearly as possible in my question :(

`layer_1 appears, disappears.`

`layer_2 appears, disappears.`

This is the flow.

In the CSS code you made, it is appearing on top of each other and getting a mess.

Comment: Look at [this example](https://media13.gimplearn.net/download/file.php/glitch-gif?id=11275), one layer needs to appear after another, to form an effect.

and not layer over layer, understand?

Comment: I just meant this when I said "can  be moderated". Anyway, I did it on the code. It's a bit slower now but easier to recognize the separation.

Comment: You can play with the percentages, delays and duration of the elements to customize it as you like. It's doing the job now.

Comment: Honestly, I can't set the percentages to match the time I need.

could you help me one more time?

between each layer, `0.2s` and `layer_5` remain static for `3s` and then repeat all over again?I identify the functioning of the code of my question. except the last layer that should remain for 3 seconds and then erase and repeat

Comment: Check it out. This is the exact time you said.

Comment: the timing is perfectly correct, but the layers are showing up without the previous one hiding it.

Comment: It's exactly what you asked for dude. In an animation this fast eyes can't recognize this is happening. Anyway, you already got it. Try to focus on and learn about animation timing in CSS. It's easy to understand. I'm sure you'll make it easily.